# wpf datatable -> datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a filled DataTable object dt and a DataGrid object declared in xaml. dt is filled in the code programatically.

What's the way to display the information in dt in the DataGrid object?

I tried

dataGrid1.DataContext = dt;
but it doesn't work

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there. You must be missing something. Try following this example : http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-the-wpf-toolkit-datagrid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say that the DataContext is just to tell the control "you can use this data" but doesn't specify which data should it use.
You can or specify the binding on your datagrid in xaml:

```
ItemsSource = {Binding }
```

( Remember to specify the columns which you need or set the AutoGenerateColumns to True)

Or you can set the itemssource in your code-behind:

```
dataGrid.1ItemsSource = dt;
```

But this will not bind the data to the DataGrid just "fire-and-show".

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) - I used the dataGrid1.ItemsSource but it doesn't like my DataTable format, any hints? :( .. I'm new with this so sorry for being noob :|

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your issue. Which .Net framework are you using? Some code might be helpful.

Comment: Oh, I found this q/a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815014/how-to-bind-a-datagrid-to-a-datatable-all-in-code-behind and it's ok now. But thx for your answer too.