# How to Bind a DataGrid to a DataTable all in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

How to bind a DataGrid to a DataTable in C# code behind? (All controls are generated in run-time, so no XAML please)

I tried Binding(), set the DataContext, set the ItemsSource, but all doesn't work:

```
/* Binding() fails */
Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Source = dataset;
bind.Path = new PropertyPath("dataset.Tables");
datagrid.SetBinding(DataSet, bind);

/* DataContext fails */
datagrid.DataContext = dataset.Tables;

/* ItemsSource fails */
datagrid.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables;
```

All I need to do is to Bind a DataGrid to a DataTable, so when there is new rows added to the DataTable, it will show automatically on the DataGrid.

I search all through stackoverflow and google but strangely I cannot find a solution.

Comment: You mean bind a dataTable to a DataGrid, you dont bind a DataGrid to a DataTable.

Comment: subscribe to the **TableNewRow** event of the DataTable and assign

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try binding to one of the Tables in your dataset:

```
datagrid.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: I was just about to type that, I think his logic of binging a DataGrid to the DataTable so it updates it the wrong way around.

Comment: @tomasmcguiness. Woah - problem solved. Thanks!! Can't wait to make it an answer with 5min limit. Btw. what is DefaultView?

Comment: DefaultView is the DataView for a DataTable. You can use this for filtering, sorting. Wpf internal transform this DefaultView to BindingListCollectionView. because of this i bind always to BindingListCollectionView direct.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to keep a good abstraction layer between your data and its representation on your forms, I would suggest you to set the property AutoGenerateColumns of your DataGridView to false and add just the columns you want displayed by hand, with the header name of your choice (in this case, do not forget to set the columns' DataPropertyName property).